# How to toggle between Pen Mode and Mouse Mode with Wacom Intuos Pro Tablet

Tags: workflow, drawing-tablet, wacom, applications, configuration

Using Wacom Intuos Pro Tablets, (Paper in my case):

When editing photos or images using Gimp, Photoshop, etc., I find it helpful to be in "**`Pen Mode`**".

But, in vector graphics, I prefer "**`Mouse Mode`**", like with Inkscape or Illustrator.

Also, when testing 3D rendering, (like quickly moving a 3D camera in a game), Mouse Mode also seems much more efficient.

***Is there a way to toggle between "`Pen Mode`" and "`Mouse Mode`" quickly***, by binding that function to the eraser, express keys, display keys, or even a keyboard shortcut?

Is there a way to create a custom macro for this - if it isn't supported "out-of-the-box"?

**Personal Work-Around:**

I have been creating separate application configuration settings using the Wacom Settings control panel, which allows either pen or mouse mode to be set for an application.

**Caveat:** It is often the case that I want to switch within the SAME application, and this workaround doesn't seem to work for this.

Answer (score 4):

On the old drivers, it was possible to set two "buttons" on the radial menu to mouse mode and pen mode. Now that this very use full feature is gone (you may ask WHY?) then the only other possibility is to change the buttons on the grip pen to mode toggle.

Go to Wacom Tablet Properties and in the tool pane click on your grip pen.
Then go down to the setting of the button on the pen and change double-click to mode toggle. Keep in mind, the double-click will instead toggle between mouse and pen mode and you just tap twice on the tablet for double-click.

It's impossible to use a Wacom tablet set only to mouse or pen mode. You have to be able to toggle quickly according to what you use the pen for and it's very strange that Wacom makes this mode toggle so hard to access. E.g. when you draw in photoshop you use pen mode when you need to change some settings you use e.g. the top button to shift quickly to mouse mode and back when you start drawing again.

Answer (score 2):

It is not perfect way, but better than nothing. I use wacom driver 6.3.11, the last one with mouse/pen mode in radial menu, and the first one with mouse height setting. So there is no any significant differences between 6.3.11 and 6.3.32 for me.[image]

Comment: Hi Vermouth, welcome to Graphic Design SE! It would appear you have accidentally created multiple accounts. Please go to our [help section](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) and contact Stack Exchange to have this issue fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Partial, and potentially 'good enough' workaround, "Display Toggle" will cycle between pen-mapped-to-one-screen, then pen-mapped-to-next-screen if you have multiple monitors... but most importantly, it will cycle back to the *current mapping* in settings.

So, if you have the settings set to Mouse-Mode, you can cycle into pen-mode and back again.  The only thing this doesn't resolve is you cannot go to pen-mode mapped to all displays, but I think that's probably a less common configuration anyway.